# How to echo some code inside a while loop?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I have been thinking for hours but i still cant get a solution for this

Basically what i want to do is to echo a separator inside a while, it should be something like this

```
$num = 1;
while($num < 3){

echo 'dog';

//function to stop while
echo 'separator';
//function to continue while

echo 'cat';

$num++;
}
```

I want to get this output

```
dog
dog
dog
separator
cat
cat
cat
```

I dont know if i explained myself well but hope you understand. Thank you very much in advance.

Update: I know i can make this with 2 while functions but is it possible to make it using only one while function?

Comment: The question seems interesting but not well explained. Can you explain more ? And is the number of echo dog equal to the number of cat ? is while the only option to use ?

Comment: $num should be 0 not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$num = 0;
$dogs = '';
$cats = '';
$seperator = 'seperator';
while($num < 3){

$dogs .= 'dog';

$cats .= 'cat';

$num++;
}
echo $dogs . $seperator . $cats;
```

Save the output of each of the dogs and cats then combine at end.

Comment: This `$num = 1;` needs to be `$num = 0;` in order to get 3x dog and 3x cat.

Comment: True, yet your answer works. But to echo one line under the other, would need to have `$seperator = 'seperator' . '<br>';` etc. (just saying)

Comment: Actually you would a '<br />' after every dog, cat and/or seperator or \r in command line.

Comment: Sure, that's another way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks to all the people who took the time to help me. This answer is the best fit as it keeps the original while condition. In my question i put the dog/cat as a simple problem but i just wanted an example so i could scale the function to my needs.

Answer (score 2):

definitely yes you can with one while ~function. :)

```
function OnlyOneWhileFunction($echoThis, $howManyTimes){
    $i = 1;
    while($i <= $howManyTimes){
        echo $echoThis."\r\n";
        $i++;
    }
}

OnlyOneWhileFunction('dog', 3);
echo 'separator';
OnlyOneWhileFunction('cat', 3);
```

Comment: This will output `dog\r\ndog\r\ndog\r\nseparatorcat\r\ncat\r\ncat\r\n` change to `echo $echoThis."\r\n";` using double quotes and not singles.

Comment: let the asker put some sweat. he too should learn aint it? ;-)

Comment: I think this answer is too literal when it comes to there only being one while loop. I'm sure the OP would have meant for only one loop to *run*, not one loop *written*.

Comment: Marty you are indeed right, problem is I am using this code with a big sql query and i cant afford to execute it 2 times. Anyways thanks sanjeev for taking your time to help me

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution:

```
$items = array_reverse(array("cat","dog"));
$output = array();

while(count($items) > 0)
{
    $item = array_pop($items);
    $output[] = implode("\n", array_fill(0, 3, $item));
}

echo implode("\nseparator\n", $output);
```

You can replace `\n` with `<br>` for HTML output (or use `nl2br`).

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work:

```
$num = 0;
while($num <= 6){
    if($num < 3)         echo 'dog<br/>';
    else if($num == 3)   echo 'separator<br/>';
    else                 echo 'cat<br/>';
    $num++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$num = 0;
while($num < 7){
if($num < 3)
echo 'dog';
elseif($num == 3)
echo 'separator';
elseif($num>3)
echo 'cat';
echo "<br>";
$num++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using a C style for loop and a function call for this:

```
$recho = function($out, $limit) {
    for ($x=0; $x<$limit; $x++) {
        echo $out . "\n";
    }
}

$recho('dog',3);
echo "seperator\n";
$recho('cat',3);
```

Put this inside a `<pre>` on a webpage to get your line breaks, or replace the `"\n"` with `<br>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach if you wanted n number of options and assuming each option is iterated over the same number of times.  I'd do some cleanup but this is a quick and dirty approach:

```
<?php

/**
 * Loops items with separator every nth time
 * @param array list of items
 * @param integer number of iterations
 * @param string separator text
 */
function loopItemsWithSeparator(array $items, $count, $separator) {

    $items = array_reverse($items);
    while(!empty($items)) {
        $item = array_pop($items);
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            echo $item . "\n";
        }

        if (count($items) > 0) {
            echo($separator . "\n");
        }
    }

}

loopItemsWithSeparator(array('dog', 'cat', 'bird'), 3, 'separator');

?>
```

Comment: didn't see the only one while loop condition, but i'll leave this here anyways.  just note that there is a nested loop in this solution...